# Virtual to Virtual Migration

Tags: migration, windows-server-2008-r2

I am totally new to sharepoint so please explain (or link) like I am five.  I have done a virtual to virtual migration of a sharepoint server from Hyper-V to ESXi.  Right now I get "cannot connect to the configuration database" when I try to access sharepoint.  The server name is the same.  Different IP\MAC addr.  I did not do the original install and the server is not in production, but it would be wonderful to have it working.

Comment: Does the old server still exist? Try to create a sql alias that points to the "old" server name on all servers in the farm to the current SQL server.

Comment: By 'server name' are you referring to the URL to access the SharePoint site or the machine name of the server itself?

Comment: The old server does exist, but it is on a different domain on the same physical network.

Comment: @DaveWise By server name, I mean the name of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the SQL Alias then its pretty easy.

If you dont setup the SQL alias then its long way....

- Install the SharePoint on new server, same patches
- Run the Config wizard and create new Config DB.
- Now create new web applications & services App.
- Now restore the Content DB from Old farm SQL server to new Farm SQL Server.[Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Few good resrources:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7b784ac2-bbdb-4c80-ae93-3b457c8a5e5c/move-sharepoint-2010-farm-to-new-server?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Since I used a V2V conversion from Hyper-V to ESXi, the server install and data are already installed on the 'new' machine.  It is essentially the same machine on different virtual hardware.